# Button for updating database not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have database with tables

- `dbo.auctions` : `[id]` `[productid]` `[lastbider]` `[bidvalue]` `[lastbid]`
- `dbo.products` : `[id]` `[name]`
- `dbo.users` : `[id]` `[name]` `[password]` `[bids]`

I need to write a procedure that checks if `[bids]` are more than 0.

If it is, `[lastbid]` is updated and `[bidvalue]` is added to it, something like `lastbid = lastbid + bidvalue`, and `[bids]` are lowered by 1, `bids = bids - 1`. And I need to connect that to `Button` in `Visual Studio`.

I wrote this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_makebid] (
    @userid int, @auctionid int
)


 AS
DECLARE @bids int, @lastbid int
SELECT @bids = COUNT (*)
FROM users
WHERE users.id = @userid

IF @bids > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE auctions
    SET lastbid = @lastbid + bidvalue
    WHERE id = @auctionid
        AND lastbid = @lastbid
    UPDATE users
    SET bids = @bids - 1
    WHERE bids = @bids
    END
```

and connected it to `Button` :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=JOVAN-PC;database=aukcija_jovan_gajic;integrated security=true"))
        {
            con.Open();
            var userid = 1;
            var auctionid = 2;


            var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_makebid", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auctionid", auctionid);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
    }
}
```

but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Main page looks like this, maybe that can give you general idea :

[image]

Comment: Try debugging your application; use try/catch to identify the error ...

Comment: How your db updated Without passing userid and auctionid value ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values for userid and auctionid then update your table..

**Example :**

```
int userid = 456789;
int auctionid = 12345;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userid;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auctionid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = auctionid;
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you pass `SqlDbType.Int` enum as a value for `@userid` and `@auctionid` parameters, which is not what you are trying to do, instead you should supply a value.

Second problem is within your stored procedure.

```
SELECT bids 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = @userid
```

has no effect at all and `IF @bids > 0` condition will be always false.

Guess you want to get number of users accepting `users.id = @userid` condition, then you should replace above select with

```
SELECT @bids = COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = @userid
```

You should end up with the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_makebid]
(
  @userid INT ,
  @auctionid INT
)
AS 
    DECLARE @bids INT, @lastbid INT

    SELECT @bids = COUNT(*)
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = @userid

    IF @bids > 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE auctions
        SET lastbid = @lastbid + bidvalue
        WHERE id = @auctionid
          AND lastbid = @lastbid

        UPDATE users
        SET bids = @bids - 1
        WHERE bids = @bids
    END
```

Notice also that `cmd.Connection = con;` line is redundant, since `Connection` is already initialized via `SqlCommand` Constructor.

Try this method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=JOVAN-PC;database=aukcija_jovan_gajic;integrated security=true"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var userid = 1;
        var auctionid = 2;

        var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_makebid", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auctionid", auctionid);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did all of that, but still nothing happens. I updated my question, maybe i am missing something in my `Home.aspx.cs` code. I am guessing i should put some code to update string i select in `ListBox`, but i am not sure.

Comment: @JovanGajic I see following lines `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auctionid", SqlDbType.Int);` in your updated answer. Have you tried to remove them while you were testing my answer ?

Comment: Mistake, i did that, just forgot to update it, i updated something else. I tried your answer but still no result.